# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have seen a few of these questions here but can't find something that applies to my code. Here is my snipet where I am getting the error:

```
left join 
    WORKQUEUE_INFO wqi
        on wqi.WORKQUEUE_ID = SUBSTRING(hxcmt.hx_comment,CHARINDEX('[',hxcmt.hx_comment)+1,(CHARINDEX(']',hxcmt.hx_comment)-CHARINDEX('[',hxcmt.hx_comment))-1)
```

HX_COMMENT returns values like this:

'Deferred until 09/13/2022 12:00 AM CDT on workqueue ADMIN-CATCH ALL QUEUE [203]'

So what I am trying to do is join on the value in the brackets in HX_COMMENT (203 from the above value)

Any ideas why this might be failing?

Comment: You posted this earlier: [Invalid length parameter pass to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75652577/invalid-length-parameter-pass-to-the-left-or-substring-function) Please don't delete and repost questions.

Comment: *"Any ideas why this might be failing?"* Because you are, as the error says, passing an invalid length parameter. Most likely the expression you have is resolved to a negative number, and you can't pass a negative value to the 3rd parameter for `SUBSTRING`.

Comment: In truth, I would fix your design. If you are meant to be joining on the value in brackets (`[]`) then it should be in it's own column in *both* tables. Then you can can simply do `wqi.WORKQUEUE_ID = hxcmt.WORKQUEUE_ID`.

Comment: Using the example string you gave us for `HX_COMMENT`, this succeeds. One of your rows must be improperly formatted for what you're trying to do.

Comment: What debugging did you do? Such as checking the results of the CHARINDEX functions, without passing them to SUBSTRING? Have you tried to identify under which circumstances you get the error? Then you can find the rows that work, the rows that error, and decide what to do next (filter out "bad" rows, or parse it differently, or return a default vakue, etc, etc).

Answer (score 1):

It becomes a small matter to trap/nullify zero values

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([HX_COMMENT] varchar(150))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('... CDT on workqueue ADMIN-CATCH ALL QUEUE [203]')
,('... CDT on workqueue ADMIN-CATCH ALL QUEUE [999] other text')
,('... CDT on workqueue ADMIN-CATCH ALL QUEUE -- No Brackets')
 

Select A.*
      ,NewVal = substring([HX_COMMENT],P1+1,P2-P1-1)
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (nullif(charindex('[',[HX_COMMENT]),0),nullif(charindex(']',[HX_COMMENT]),0) ) ) B(P1,P2)
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Should possibly also take care for other "malformed" strings, such as `'Ooops ]555['`?